# ASCII and newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Here's a string:

```
"Hello\r\nHow are you?"
```

I saved this string into my DB two ways:
1) by copying this exact string into the console then saving;
2) by typing it (with an actual newline rather than `\r\n`) into the object's form and submitting it.

**Both** results return the above string on the console. Both are encoded in UTF-8.

However, **only the first** responds to `.ascii_only?` with `true`.

1. Why is this the case? How can I save the above string as ascii_only with method #1?
2. How can I convert method #1's string to `ascii_only?`?

Comment: I tried both #1 and #2, and for both getting result as `true`